# How to update Clojure Leiningen Emacs tool chain on Mac OS

Tags: emacs, clojure, leiningen

I have a working Clojure-1.4.0 / emacs24 / leiningen-2.0 tool chain working on Mac OSX 10.8.  I got it going very quickly by following the instructions at the following URLs:

```
http://clojure.org/getting_started
https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen
http://clojure-doc.org/articles/tutorials/emacs.html
```

One way I check that it works is I go to a project directory and type

```
lein test
```

and it runs all the unit tests in my project directory. I can also do `C-c ,` in clojure-mode in emacs, and it does the same thing. Great! Now the question: all this runs the clojure installation I have in `~/clojure-1.4.0`, which I see by typing

```
lein repl
```

in a project directory.  I have a new installation of clojure in `~/clojure-1.5.0` now, and I would like to make leiningen and emacs point to that new version.  However, during the setup of leiningen and the emacs mode, I never manually told them where to find the clojure version. They found that magically and opaquely -- in fact, the whole process was very magic, and that was great at that time. I suppose I could tear everything down and build it up again from scratch, but that seems brute-forcedly inefficient.  I could also hack-replace the files in the 1.4 directory with the files from the 1.5 directory.  That might work one time, but it's so obviously wrong I really don't want to think about it.  I need to do this the right way so that when the next version updates come along, I can keep the toolchain going as smoothly as possible.

I am just starting with all this, so I am  far from mastery of any of these tools and I'll be grateful for noob-level advice on keeping it all  going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change clojure version in `./project.clj` in your project directory:

```
:dependencies [... [org.clojure/clojure "1.5.0"] ...]
```

test:

```
$ lein repl

user=> *clojure-version*
{:major 1, :minor 5, :incremental 0, :qualifier nil}
```

**Edit:**

> They found that magically and opaquely

Default clojure version is built into lein's `project.clj` template which renders to your `<name>/project.clj` file when you do `lein new <name>`.

Comment: Where is lein's `project.clj` template stored?  Is it editable?  Groveling around `/bin/lein` and `~/.lein` did not reveal anything obvious.

Comment: Afair it's somewhere in resources directory inside leiningen jar.